# vue.js: always load a settings.scss file in every vue style section

Tags: sass, webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I find myself repeating this same pattern in every .vue file, in order to use variables, etc.:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "../styles/settings.scss";

  .someclass { color: $some-variable; }
</style>
```

or if it's nested in a folder I have to remember to be careful with the path:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "../../styles/settings.scss";

</style>
```

Is there a way to globally import that `settings.scss` file in every .vue file I create? I looked in the docs and didn't see it, but maybe I missed it, or maybe this is something I need to leverage webpack to do?

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official docs have been updated since I asked this question: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

For anyone else viewing this in 2017 and beyond, check out the instructions under 'loading a global settings file'.

Comment: Does this also allow use of global mixins?

Comment: That link no longer talks about "loading a global settings file" -- still looking for a simple way to load global css in vue 2.x.

Comment: @GaryO it's in the official docs, there's a huge thread on github about it too with many examples

Answer (score 14):

I have struggled with the same question for a while. But there's a really simple fix. This feature comes through node-sass itself.

so you can declare your scss globals in a file, say `globals.scss` whose path is:

```
/src/scss/globals.scss
```

Now you can simply edit the `vue-loader` config:

```
loaders: {
  sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax=1&data=@import "./src/scss/globals"',
  scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?data=@import "./src/scss/globals";'
}
```

and voila! You have the scss globals available across all your vue components. Hope it helps!

**Update:**

A lot of settings have been updated in new releases of vue. So the above changes may not seem trvial in latest vue projects. So I'll brief how everything is tied together-

**Short version:**

Find `build/utils.js` which would contain a method (most probably named `cssLoaders()` ). This method would return an object like this :

```
return {
   ...
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
   ...
  }
```

You simply need to change the `scss/sass` specific line to something like this:

```
 return {
   ...
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders(['css', 'sass?data=@import "~assets/styles/app";']),
   ...
  }
```

**Long Version:**

`webpack.base.conf.js` contains `vue-loader` in it, it would look something like this :

```
    ...    
    {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: vueLoaderConfig
        },
    ...
```

The `vueLoaderConfig` variable is imported from the `vue-loader.conf.js` file, which is equal to this object:

```
    {
      loaders: utils.cssLoaders( Obj ),  // actual settings coming from cssLoader method of build/utils.js
      transformToRequire: {
       //some key value pairs would be here
      }
    }
```

in `build/utils.js` file we find the `cssLoaders()` method which returns:
    ....

```
     return {
        css: generateLoaders(),
        postcss: generateLoaders(),
        less: generateLoaders('less'),
        sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
        scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
        stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
        styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
      }
```

You simply need to update the above code with updated `scss` configuration like this:

```
       ...
        {
           ...
            scss: generateLoaders(['css', 'sass?data=@import"~assets/scss/main";']),
           ...
         }
        ...
```

Thus, the variables/mixins written in `src/assets/scss/main.scss` file will be available across all your components.

Answer (score 10):

I reckon you're using webpack? 
You can require the `settings.scss` file in your app.js file something like this

```
require("!style!css!sass!./file.scss");
```

hence when it's compiled. All your components will get it. You won't have to require it on each of them.

Comment: Not sure about this one, since Vueify automatically scopes all styles to apply only to the particular component

Comment: If it's included in your main, it will be applied to all.

Comment: Has anyone tried doing this with Vue2? Using the basic vue-cli webpack starter and I've added this `require` line to both the App.vue and main.js file and haven't had any success.

Comment: Using vue2/webpack2, while the scss file can be included this way, the variables inside do not seem to be included in any component's <style> section.

Answer (score 7):

If you use the Vue webpack template, you can fix it with one line of code in `build/utils.js`:
`scss: generateLoaders(['css', 'sass?data=@import "~assets/styles/app";'])`

Then, in `src/assets/styles/app`, you add all the @imports and voilà!

Answer (score 6):

For users using Vue CLI, read https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules. Example:

```js
// vue.config.js
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // pass options to sass-loader
      sass: {
        // @/ is an alias to src/
        // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.scss`
        data: `@import "@/variables.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This fixed it for me perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can globally import a file. I probably wouldn't do this anyway, it's not explicit enough. If someone wants to move that component into another project they would have *no* idea it relies on that file.

You can, however, make the path management a lot easier. You can add this to your webpack config file...

```
sassLoader: {
  includePaths: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, './sass')
  ]
},
```

Then you can include files from your projects root `/sass` directory freely without worrying about the paths.

Answer (score 3):

If you store all your components in the same directory, your path to your settings.scss will always stay the same.

This is the desired functionality of webpack. The principle is to have as little globals as possible and only include what you need, keeping your project lean, efficient, and easy to reason about.

Perhaps you should restructure your components/styling such that you don't have so many custom styles within each Vue component (build your own bootstrap?), therefore you won't have to include a certain stylesheet inside every Vue component.

This doesn't really answer your question but it might guide you towards aligning with the principles behind the tools you've chosen to work with.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Been there - unfortunately there is not a way to do this without importing the file in each component.  To get around this, you could try creating helper classes with `color: $some-variable` and `background-color: $some-variable` which may cover some of your use cases.

If you do import a file in each one, make sure it only contains variables.  You don't want to include style rules multiple times.

Otherwise, I would create separate `.scss` files for each component.  You can still use `.vue` templates for html and js, but keep your styles separate.  This is probably the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is set the `settings.scss` file's folder a alias in webpack,

maybe `settings.scss` is not global need, maybe you are also need a like setting2.scss file, but `settings.scss` is conflict with setting2.scss,  you can only choose to introduce a file in this case.

webpack config like this:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    '~styles': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles'),
}
```

so, you can import `settings.scss` in your component

```
<style lang="scss">
   @import "~styles/settings.scss";
</style>
```

Comment: This is basically what I use, but I take it a step further. I'll have one global component that every component sits inside and that takes global site styles, and then every other component will import any SCSS that doesn't output styles directly, such as mixins. This avoids webpack spitting the same styles out multiple times.