# Best way to have global css in Vuejs

Tags: css, import, vue.js

What is the best way to have a global css file in Vuejs for all components? (Default css like bg color, button styling, etc)

- import a css file in the index.html
- do `@import` in main component
- put all the css in the main component (but that would be a huge file)

Comment: Thanks @mods for not closing this as opionion-based. It's actually helping me a lot.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Import css in your index.html, but if you're using webpack you can just import your stylesheets in your main js config and all your components will get the css.

As comments below suggested if using webpack adding this to main.js works:

```
import './assets/css/main.css';
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm using webpack so in my main.js file I did `require('./assets/css/main.css');` and it works now.

Comment: @Jordy I guess the best approach would be using the sass-loader to get it done. Takes just a few words to get it done. Here's the explained solution- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46015906/5013932

Comment: @Jordy there is no need for `require`, when it can be done with `import './assets/css/main.css')`.

Comment: An example would be nice for people

Comment: DO NOT USE your index file if you plan on utilizing history mode. It will cause major issues on refresh. Always webpack!

Comment: Warning : Good solution. It run. But if you want a dynamic system you can't do this into response promise for example.

Answer (score 43):

I found the best way is to create a new file in the **assets folder**, I created as `global.css` but you can name anything of your choice. Then, import this file `global.css` file in the `main.js`.

*Note: Using this approach you can also create multiple files if you think the global.css is getting really large then simply import all those files in the main.js.*

> @\assets\global.css

```
/* move the buttons to the right */
.buttons-align-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

---

> main.js

---

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routes'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// Importing the global css file
import "@/assets/global.css"

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Do you know if this approach has the same effect as adding it to the `App.vue` ? as the above answer from @c24b?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested whether it has got the same effect or not. But, I prefer to separate my files (if they make a sense).

Answer (score 15):

In App.vue you can add a `style` property to declare you CSS file:

```
<style>
  @import './assets/css/global.css';
</style>
```

Comment: Do you know if this approach has the same effect as adding it to the `main.js` ? as the answer from @Coder Absolute meaning can you add more imports here as well ?

Comment: This has not the exact same effect as in main.js the import are executed at one following the order of the declaration of the import and not the order of the execution of the template.

Answer (score 5):

1. create a new css file in your assets folder for example : `global.css`
2. import "global.css" to main.js

```
import '@/assets/global.css';
```

Comment: Please show inside of the main.css

Answer (score 4):

You can also do something like this: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-import-a-sass-file-into-every-vue-component-in-an-app/

My folders are mostly structured like this:

```
 - src
   - assets
     - _global.scss
     - _colors.scss
     - _fonts.scss
     - _paragraphs
     - index.scss // <-- import all other scss files.
```

This also works with normal css.

Comment: Be careful PeeJee, the solution your are proposing is just recommended for share scss variables across the entire application components. Further information here:
[https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/) "You have to make sure that the files that you import in the data configuration contain only SASS code that doesn't get rendered, such as variables, mixins and functions. Otherwise, that code will end up repeated for each component in...

Comment: ... the final post-processed css file"  – XaviPS [Converted to comment from answer, but it didn't fit]

Comment: Thank you for the information @XaviPS, didn't know that!

Answer (score 3):

There are to two ways, as I know, to achieve this.

### Approach 1

Utilize `vue.config.js` configuration, less config can also be replaced with sass:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      less: {
        additionalData: `@import '@/style/common.less';`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Approach 2

In your .vue file, make your style looks like this:

```
<style lang="less">
@import (reference) "../../style/variables.less";
#app {
  background: @bgColor;
}
</style>
```

Note: the `(reference)` flag is used to make variables defined in `variables.less` take effect. If you don't have variables, `@import "../../style/variables.less";` is sufficient to do the trick.

For your reference, you can also take a look at this link:

https://github.com/tjcchen/vue-practice/tree/master/multipage-app

Answer (score 1):

Sass has recently announced their new module system which needs to be used by @use and @forward.

My approach is the best way to use scss with Vite.
Use defineConfig to setup global scss (colors, mixin) and reuse in all components without import

```
css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@use "~/styles/main.scss" as *;`,
      },
    },
  },
```

Here: [Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-5bon7k?file=vite.config.js)

> Note: If you see the same CSS is being loaded multiple times.

When you use `@use "~/styles/main.scss" as *;` equivalent import all styles to your file.

So, inside `styles` folder must be stored variables, mixins and must use partial Sass files

If you want to style for common or reset, it must be put into `src/index.scss`

```
// Put in common css or reset css here.
:root {
  --danger: #fe2c55;
  --danger-dark: #d60032;
  --danger-light: #ff5c83;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I am learning Vue and I have implemented this method. When I am on a dev server, I can see the same css is being loaded multiple times. Is that only happening whilst on a dev server? I haven't yet tested a production version of my code yet.

Comment: Sure,
When you use `@use "~/styles/main.scss" as *;` equivalent import all scss to your file.

So, inside `styles` folder must be stored variables of scss
If you want to style for common or reset, it must be put into `src/index.scss`

```
// Put in common css or reset css here.
:root {
  --danger: #fe2c55;
  --danger-dark: #d60032;
  --danger-light: #ff5c83;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a vue.config.js file in your root directory
2. Create a styles folder inside your src folder and you can create your global style file here for example **base.scss**
3. to use scss install two dependencies

```
npm install node-loader sass-loader
```

4. Inside your vue.config.js paste code from below

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
            additionalData: `@import "@/styles/base.scss";`
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: I am learning Vue and I have implemented this method. When I am on a dev server, I can see the same css is being loaded multiple times. Is that only happening whilst on a dev server? I haven't yet tested a production version of my code yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add css within the `<link>` element, inside the `<head>` section of an HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/styles.css">
    /* ... */
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```