# Global less stylesheets not loaded with vue.config.js in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, less

I wanted to use a gobal stylesheet for my Vue application.. In the video by Earth is Square on YouTube he used this code in his `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import '@/styles/base.scss';`,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

So I googled and found out that less also supports this.. Just replacing the `scss` with `less`... but it isn't working.. So what is the correct way to load a global stylesheet in Vue.js?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438094/best-way-to-have-global-css-in-vuejs

Comment: This is what I saw.. But this says I have to import that global.less in all my components.. But I think There would be a better option.. Thanks