# Global SCSS variable via VueJS Component

Tags: javascript, sass, vue.js

If I have a VueJS component inside another, the parent with a none scoped styles, the child with scoped styles. Any reason why I wouldn't be able to access a scss variable from the parent referenced in the child?

Sorry if that is a little confusing, heres pretty much what I have to help:

(parent)

```html
// some <template> and <script> here.
<style lang="scss">
  $background: #09f;
</style>
```

(child)

```html
// some <template> and <script> here.
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .somediv {
      background: $background;
  }
</style>
```

I just get an error, Undefined variable: **"$background"**.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928380/vue-js-always-load-a-settings-scss-file-in-every-vue-style-section/46015906#46015906 could be of help.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this solution, it just seems l'm going out of my way to do something that should be done the way I'm trying to do it.