# How to use mixins from .scss files in .vue files?

Tags: vue.js

I got an error - "no mixin named sm" when trying to use my scss mixins in Single Vue Components - sm is my mixin variable name.

My _mixins.scss is in my assets/styles folder. How can i use my mixins in .vue files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATED**: I have found my answers.

I’ll leave the the links below for any others who might encounter this in future.

**Globally importing sass/scss**

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/149

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/883#issuecomment-317557131

[vue.js: always load a settings.scss file in every vue style section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928380/vue-js-always-load-a-settings-scss-file-in-every-vue-style-section)

I also found out that there is documentation:
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/pre-processors.html

Answer (score -1):

You may need to import the file where your mixin is located to the component that is trying to access it.

Something like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Example Component Template...</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ExampleComponent'
},
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import '../assets/styles/mixins.scss';

// Now you can use your mixin here...

</style>
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the reply. But i'm looking for a cleaner way because it guess very repetitive to import into every single vue components..how can i make my sass variables and mixins available without @import?